# I'm trying to return socket id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, express.io

I'm trying to use [express.io](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/) module for the first time and I like it. It's really extended part of [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) and express.js.

I'm trying to return socket.id in app.io.route event. How can I get client unique id using express.io?

```js
app.io.route('debug', function(socket) {
    console.log( socket.id );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `route` function receives a [SocketRequest](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/lib#socketrequest) object, so you'll need the following:

```
app.io.route('debug', function (req) {
    console.log( req.io.id );
});
```

You can also access the socket.io socket directly (`req.socket`) if needed, but you should probably use the RequestIO object above if possible.

[Routing documentation](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples#routing)

Comment: I have already tried req.io.id, but it doesn't work. It shows me undefined message!